# Union 2 table with diff schema

Tags: sql, join, union

Following is the requirement and given table schema

Write a query in Canvas using Table 1 ,Table 2 & Table 3 only for books available in both the tables with below conditions

- It has to be non-fiction and have rating above 4.2 .
- Introduce a column using price to show grouping.
- Union Table 3.

[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfHTF.png)

I was able to solve the first point. However I am not able to wrap my head around the point 2 & 3. Do you guys think its an incorrect question?

My Query:

```
Select table2.book, table1.genre, table2.ratings, table2.reviews, table2.type, table2.price 
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.book_name = table2.book
where table1.genre = 'non-fiction' 
and table2.ratings > 4.2
```

Comment: Replace your table schema screenshot with formatted CREATE TABLE scripts.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to UNION two tables with a different number of columns.

UNION is a set operator which combines data vertically across the tables. So, the columns must be same number, same datatype and same order.

The trick here is to use NULL for the extra columns present in both the tables if you want to use UNION. You can match the number of columns using this way.

```
(select table2.book,table2.author,NULL as noOfCopies,table1.genre,table2.ratings,table2.reviews,table2.type,sum(table2.price) as totalprice
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.book_name = table2.book
where table1.genre = 'non-fiction'  and table2.ratings > 4.2 
group by table2.book, table1.genre, table2.ratings, table2.reviews,table2.type)
UNION
select NULL as book, author_name, noOfCopies, NULL as genre, NULL as ratings, NULL as reviews, NULL as type, NULL as totalprice from table3;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do union with table3,used inner join to link table2 and table3 with author name

```
Select table2.book, table1.genre, table2.ratings, table2.reviews, table2.type, sum(table2.price), sum(noofcopies)
from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.book_name = table2.book 
inner join table3 on table2.author=table3.author_name
where table1.genre = 'non-fiction' and table2.ratings > 4.2 
group by table2.book, table1.genre, table2.ratings, table2.reviews,table2.type
```

Comment: Hi,

Could you explain your code? As in how did we union the table 3?

Comment: I think that `table3.noofcopies` must be summarized, not counted.

Comment: `table3` may contain more than one matching row per `table2`. Join multiplying will occur over `sum(table2.price)`.